# How to link or copy in Ant?

Tags: ant, groovy

I want in Ant to do the equivalent of:

```
mkdir -p build/test
ln */build/test build/test
```

or:

```
mkdir -p build/test
ln -s */build/test build/test
```

or:

```
mkdir -p build/test
cp */build/test build/test
```

I've tried:

```
<groovy>
    new File('build/test').mkdirs()
    'ln */build/test/TEST-*.xml build/test'.execute()
</groovy>
```

and:

```
<mkdir dir="build/test"/>
<copy todir="build/test">
    <fileset dir=".">
        <filename name="*/build/test/TEST-*.xml"/>
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

It seems that globbing in  isn't very straightforward and the  Ant task preserves the directory name. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: This is really two questions. Dealing with the copy problem, first of all the syntax for your fileset is incorrect. Secondly, you can use a nested "<flattenmapper/>" element to remove leading directory names from the copied files.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor, can you provide the proper ant code as an answer for us non-Ant-elite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example as requested:

```
<mkdir dir="build/test"/>

<copy todir="build/test">
    <fileset dir=".">
        <include name="*/build/test/TEST-*.xml"/>
    </fileset>
    <flattenmapper/>
</copy>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<groovy>
    new File('build/test').mkdirs()
    new AntBuilder().fileScanner {
        fileset(dir:'.', includes:'*/build/test/TEST-*.xml')
    }.each {
        "ln ${it} build/test".execute()
    }
</groovy>
```

Comment: To avoid running an OS command you could invoke the ANT symlink task: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/symlink.html